# How to sort azure storage blobs numerically rather than lexicographically?

Tags: c#, azure

I have some code I am writing that pulls all blobs from my storage container and then does some logic. Here is how I am pulling my blobs:

```
await foreach (Page<BlobHierarchyItem> page in container.GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync(prefix: prefix, delimiter: "/").AsPages())
                {
                   //Some logic here
                }
```

The issue I am running into is that my blobs are pulled lexicographically but I need them being pulled numerically in order instead. I am new to this so I am unsure if theres a way to sort these after pulling them or if there is an actual way to pull them in numerically.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The blobs returned in the response are sorted by name, which by design is a string and hence lexicographically sorted.

Unfortunately, there is no way to change this at the API level, but you could first fetch all the blobs into memory first and then sort locally as you see fit.

Since the `GetBlobs*` methods don't really fetch the content of the blobs, it shouldn't be taxing up to a certain limit but it would be best to test this for your scenario before using it in production.